# How can we remove / customize Azure AD B2C authentication webview page title bar in Xamarin forms?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

A title bar is displayed in the web view activity when using Azure AD B2C authentication service with MSAL in Xamarin forms. I have attached a screen shot of it running on an android phone below. I have the following questions :

1) How do I remove it? Is it even possible?

2) Also Is it possible to customize the top bar? Change the colors, font size etc. If so how?

3) How do I change the text of the top bar? Is localization possible for the text in the top bar based on user's language settings in the app?

Thanks a ton in advance!!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should be able to customize the elements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui#create-a-sign-up-and-sign-in-user-flow

Comment: Did you use webview in the  NavigationPage ? or NavigationPage wrap the contentpage, if so you could add `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` in the contentPage like following xaml, `<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsWebViewTest"
             x:Class="FormsWebViewTest.MainPage"
              NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">`

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT The link for the microsoft doc only tells you on how to customize the user flows not the embedded web view of the MSAL SDK for xamarin.

Comment: @L.Leon The page containing the embedded web view shown in the screenshot is part of the MSAL SDK and is not something like a content page that you can "push async".

Answer (score 1):

I finally used a custom web view instead of MSAL and checked the web view's URL whenever it changed using PropertyChanged(). If the web view contains the redirection URL then I hide the web view and parse the token that is provided along with it to get the result of the user's action in ADB2C.

Comment: Can you elaborate how that worked? Can you provide a code example?